# Optional Argument from a User C++

Tags: c++

I'm making a command-line word editor program. The user is prompted to input a control character to make a change to the file. I'm having trouble with command 'D' which deletes either a single line of text, or a range of text.

```
input D:
        D 3       --deletes line 3
        D 2 8     --deletes lines 2 to 8 inclusively
```

How do you make it so that the second line is optional? I have cin << char << int << int, but I can't find a way to make that optional.

Comment: Read an entire line and parse it separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do

```
std::string line; 
std::getline(std::cin,line);
```

and then analyze the line manually, first splitting it into words.

It could be useful to have a function:

```
void ToWords(const std::string &line, std::vector<std::string> &words);
```

But the implementation is left as an exercise to the reader ;-).

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity, why wouldn't you prototype that: `std::vector<std::string> ToWords(const std::string& line)` ?

Comment: @MichaelWilson to avoid a potential copy by return.